# Create excel-compatible CSV file with python?

Tags: python, excel, csv

I am trying to create a csv file using python that is truly Excel-compatible (I am using Excel 2007, if that makes any difference).

Here is the sort of thing I'm trying to do

```
import csv

data = [ ['9-1', '9-2', '9-3'] ]

fd = open('test.csv', 'wb')
try:
    writer = csv.writer(fd, dialect='excel', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    writer.writerows(data)

finally:
    fd.close()
```

This creates a csv file that contains:

```
"9-1","9-2","9-3"
```

When I load it in Excel, I get the columns:

```
09-Jan  09-Feb  09-Mar
```

[Grrr, thanks Excel. Seriously, what is the point of quotes?]

Now, I have [read elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904519/how-to-show-long-numbers-in-excel) that in order to get Excel to treat strings as literal they must be prefixed by an equals sign `="Like This"`. So what I really want to produce is:

```
="9-1",="9-2",="9-3"
```

Is there any way to do this with the `csv` module in python? I'm guessing it will involve creating a [custom dialect](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0305/), but I can't see any variable that would give me the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, thanks for all your help, I've come up with a rough solution, so I thought I'd share it here.

It's not the prettiest of solutions but it works for my purposes. A warning though: It will break if you have any quotes in your strings!

```
import csv
import re

data = [ ['9-1', '9-2', '9-3'] ]


def quoteCsvData(data):
    for x, row in enumerate(data):
        for y, item in enumerate(row):
             if data[x][y] != '':
                 data[x][y] = r'="' + data[x][y] + r'"'
    return data

def unquoteCsvData(data):
    for x, row in enumerate(data):
        for y, item in enumerate(row):
            if data[x][y] != '':
                m = re.match(r'="([^"]*)"',data[x][y])
                if m:
                    data[x][y] =  m.group(1)
    return data


fd = open('test2.csv', 'wb')
data = quoteCsvData(data)
try:
    writer = csv.writer(fd, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', 
                            quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, 
                            escapechar='\\')
    writer.writerows(data)

finally:
    fd.close()

fd = open('test2.csv', 'rb')
try:
    reader = csv.reader(fd, delimiter=',', 
                            quotechar='|', 
                            quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, 
                            escapechar='\\')
    data = []
    for row in reader:
        data.append(row)

finally:
    fd.close()

data = unquoteCsvData(data)

print data
```

Update: removed spamming of empty cells with lots of `=""`

Answer (score 8):

If your aim is just writing a list as a table on Excel. You can try below sample, where ";" and dialect='excel-tab' property enables us to switch between coloumns.

```
import csv

RESULTS = [
    ['val_col1;','val_col2;','val_col3']
]
resultFile = open("testExcel.csv",'wb')
resultWriter= csv.writer(resultFile, dialect='excel-tab')
resultWriter.writerows(RESULTS)
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're importing your CSV file into Excel using Excel's CSV importer. Counterintuitive, I know, but you should not import CSV files that way. Instead, import them as text files (i.e., name with a `txt` extension). Then you will have the opportunity to specify the type of each column and can properly choose Text for columns that look like dates to Excel.

If you're looking for a turnkey "here is a file you can open in Excel" approach, try [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/) (not my original recommendation [pyXLWriter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyxlwriter/)) and avoid CSV entirely.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the file extension to .txt which forced Excel to bring up the text importer wizard. However, I have to select each column individually and choose to import as Text (there is no way to select more than one column). With 100s of columns, this is not really a usable solution for me :-(

Comment: You *can* choose multiple columns and change them all at once with Shift-Click in Step 3.

Comment: Oh yeah. It's working now... I guess I must have tried Ctrl and not Shift. Thanks

Comment: You could also consider xlwt as another way to write excel files directly from python which is available at http://www.python-excel.org/  It has worked quite well for me on a couple of projects.

Comment: -1 for pyXLWriter. That is as one with the Norwegian Blue Parrot. Even though sourceforge shows 12 downloads this week. Did you cause that?? It is not maintained (last update: 6 years ago), writes Excel 5/7 XLS files, and is buggy.

Comment: Hundreds of columns? How many hundreds? If it's more that 256 columns, you'll need something like pyopenxl; otherwise use xlwt.

Comment: Found pyXLWriter recommended on a forum as being easy to use. It had 12 downloads when I found it too, so none of those downloads were a result of this. Writing an old format of Excel wouldn't be a problem for this application.

Comment: ... as for the bugs, I'll defer to you on that, and have edited to recommend xlwt.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, Excel 2007 is not even compatible with itself.  If you type 9-1 into an empty spreadsheet, it converts it to 1-Sep as soon as you leave the cell.  If you change the cell format from General to Text, you can enter the string literals unchanged and save it as a .csv file, but when you read the same file into a blank spreadsheet (with General format) it gets reconverted to dates.

Excel saves the file as

```
9-1,9-2,9-3
```

without quotes and without "=" signs.  Even setting the cell formats to Text before reading the csv file doesn't work for me - it imports as dates (display value 1-Sep, cell value 9/1/2011) with the 3 cells in Custom format; the rest of the cells are converted to General.

Edit:  A csv file containing:

```
"9-1",'9-2',='9-3',=''9-4''
```

reads into the spreadsheet as:

```
1-Sep  '9-2'  ='9-3'  ="9-4"
```

So the `=` doesn't do any good, but at least the single quotes will get a string literal, with the quotes preserved.   Someone more knowlegeable in Excel will have to help with getting rid of the quotes; "paste values" doesn't strip them off.

Comment: Yep, Excel sucks. I wouldn't even be using it except that some people in my workplace insist on using it to view data.

Answer (score -4):

try::

```
dialect=csv.excel
```

as in

```
import csv
csv.excel
```

- lineterminator '\r\n'
- skipinitialspace False
- quoting 0
- delimiter ','
- quotechar '"'
- doublequote True

For me its a bit of a black art that has never bothered me enough to go read the code, but the little experimentation I did always got excel (2003) to behave well enough with the above formats.

Comment: This does exactly the same thing as `dialect='excel'`, i.e., not what the OP wants.

Answer (score -4):

```
data = [ ['9-1', '9-2', '9-3'] ]
fd = open('test.csv', 'wb')
for row in data:
    for x in row:
        fd.write('="{}",'.format(x))
    fd.write('\n')
```

Comment: The problem isn't getting Python to write a file, it's getting Excel to read a .csv file without mangling the data.